# Is it possible to listen multiple ports from same IP in network discovery?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I'm trying to make a server search mechanic in Unity Mirror, using NetworkDiscovery class. My clients can successfully listen and list the servers with the specified port on the LAN. But when I create multiple servers in the same IP, clients can only listen one port at a time. Is it possible to listen all ports (all within a range) on an IP? Thanks in advance?

Comment: Normally yes you can open a number of ports already not in use. However. Try it and see

Comment: @BugFinder I can open multiple servers on same IP with different ports. The problem is, I can only see the server I'm listening.